# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'PKL567'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns that I have selected. In these columns there are numbers to which I would like to add 0's to get a 10 digit number.
These columns are composed of numbers but can be of several types (object, int, or float). And when I wanted to do the transformation to int (to remove the decimals) and then to str (to do the transformation), I realised that there were not only numbers but also strings in a column. How to make to only ignore the string in a column and to proceed to the transformation only on the numbers.

columns = ['a','b','c']

Data[columns] = Data[columns].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(10))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'PKL567'

Answer (score 0):

If there is combination strings and integers simplier is not convert to integers, onkly convert to strings and prepend `0` by `zfill` like:

```
columns = ['a','b','c']
Data[columns] = Data[columns].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\.0$','').str.zfill(10))
```

Comment: Yes but for some numbers, with this method I get for example this when there is a decimal number: 00393865.0

Comment: That's fine, but how to avoid adding 0 to the str ?

Comment: @ascha - It is added automatically (because floats), so removed by `.str.replace('\.0$','')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas' built-in string replace function on a column together with regular expression matching:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col': ['PKL567']}
)
```

```
      col
0  PKL567
```

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('[a-zA-Z]', '0')
```

```
      col
0  000567
```